# read() returns 0 before all text from stdin has been read

Tags: c, io

I'm doing an assignment where I must accept input from `stdin` and write it to a file. One of the requirements is to keep memory being used at any given time low and use `read()` to do so. I'm using a buffer of size `4096` and the idea is that `read()` will be called until the buffer is full, then `write()` will call until the buffer has been written entirely to the file, then the process continues with `read` continuing from where it left off and overwriting the buffer until either

a) the content length in bytes set by the user has been written or

b) the end of the `stdin` contents has been reached.

I'm running into a problem where `read` will only ever read `4095` bytes at which time it will return `0` and only ever `0`. I've read the man page for `read` and understand that `0` is returned when the end of file is reached, so I'm not sure why `read()` is returning `0`.

```
void executeSetCommand(const char *filename, int contentLength) {
    int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Operation Failed fd -1 line 44 \n");
        exit(15);
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    ssize_t bytesWrote = 0;
    ssize_t totalWritten = 0; // Total bytes written so far
    ssize_t toWrite; // Bytes to write in the current iteration
    int loopcounter = 0;

    while (totalWritten < contentLength) {
        loopcounter++;
        fprintf(stderr, "loopcounter %d, \n", loopcounter);
        // Read up to the size of the buffer or whatever is left to read to meet contentLength
        fprintf(stderr, "totalwritten: %zd\n", totalWritten);
        ssize_t maxReadSize = min((size_t) sizeof(buffer), (size_t) contentLength - totalWritten);
        fprintf(stderr, "Max Read Size: %zd \n", maxReadSize);

        //the offending read call
        bytesRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, maxReadSize);

        fprintf(stderr, "bytesread: %zd \n", bytesRead);
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, " \nbytesRead <= 0 \n");
            // Handle read error or end of input
            break;
        }

        ssize_t bytesLeftToWrite = bytesRead; // Bytes left to write from the current read
        fprintf(stderr, "this is reached \n");
        while (bytesLeftToWrite > 0) {
            toWrite = bytesLeftToWrite; // Write all of the remaining bytes unless there's an error
            bytesWrote = write(fd, buffer, toWrite);
            fprintf(stderr, "\nbyteswrote: %zd\n", bytesWrote);
            if (bytesWrote <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, " \n bytesWrote <= 0 \n");
                // Handle write error
                break;
            }

            bytesLeftToWrite -= bytesWrote; // Decrease the count of bytes left to write
            totalWritten += bytesWrote; // Update the total written bytes
        }

        if (totalWritten >= contentLength) {
            fprintf(stderr, "we think we have written >= contentlength");
            // If we have written up to contentLength, stop
            break;
        }
    }

    close(fd);
    fprintf(stdout, "OK\n");
}
```

This function works and will write all input when there are less than 4096 characters of input, but if I put in say 10000 as the content length and input 12000 characters of text to `stdin`, the function will only write the first 4095 and then hang because `read` will only return 0, preventing `contentlength` from being reached. There aren't any newlines in the content entered to `stdin`.

Here is an example of the output: bytesread: 4096 this is reached byteswrote: 4096 loopcounter 2, totalwritten: 4096 contentlength: 8190 contentlength - totalwritten: 4094 Max Read Size: 4094 bytesread: 0 this is reached loopcounter 3, totalwritten: 4096 contentlength: 8190 contentlength - totalwritten: 4094 Max Read Size: 4094 bytesread: 0 this is reached loopcounter 4, totalwritten: 4096 contentlength: 8190 contentlength - totalwritten: 4094 Max Read Size: 4094

It looks like the issue is with the max line length of the input terminal being 4096. I'm feeding input through the terminal and not via a file which I will try doing now.

Comment: You should break out of the loop when `read()` returns 0, it means you reached EOF. This will happen when the length of stdin is an exact multiple of `4096`.

Comment: The problem is that read() always returns 0 on the second loop, regardless of input size when input size > 4096. output: bytesread: 4096 
this is reached 

byteswrote: 4096
loopcounter 2, 
totalwritten: 4096
contentlength: 8190
contentlength - totalwritten: 4094
Max Read Size: 4094  bytesread: 0 
this is reached 
loopcounter 3, 
totalwritten: 4096
contentlength: 8190
contentlength - totalwritten: 4094
Max Read Size: 4094 
 
 
 
 bytesread: 0 
this is reached 
loopcounter 4, 
totalwritten: 4096
contentlength: 8190
contentlength - totalwritten: 4094
Max Read Size: 4094

Comment: I ran your code. It works fine for me as long as the input file has at least `contentLength` bytes. It goes into an infinite loop if the input file is shorter.

Comment: There is no problem in the code, (I mean, there are many problems, but none that would prevent it from working,) therefore the problem must be in your methodology.

Comment: Also: `executeSetCommand` is a terrible name for this function, given what it does. A decent name might be `copyStdinToFile`.

Comment: Also: Get rid of all the `printf()` statements.  They are useless to us, because we cannot see what they output, and they are useless to you, because if you want to know what your code does, you should be using a debugger. In some cases they are even misleading. (e.g. "bytesRead <= 0")

Comment: Put the output of the program in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to have a small memory footprint, your approach is very inefficient.  The best is to allow `stdio.h` to control the buffer size (as it does it best, based on the output channel) and then proceed *ala K&R style*, this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for strerror() function */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno macro */

void executeSetCommand(const char *filename, int contentLength)
{
    FILE *out = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!out) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__":%d: fopen: %s: %s\n",
                __LINE__, filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(15);
    }
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && contentLength-- > 0) {
        fputc(c, out);
    }
    fclose(out);
    printf("Ok\n");
}
```

(memory foot print of this code is the most efficient --while smaller-- case selected by the `stdio` package)

This approach has two advantages (very large advantages):

1. Your code is more compact, simple and easy to maintain.
2. You allow `stdio` package to decide what buffer size is the best to achieve best performance (depending on things you don't control now, like the filesystem best buffering size, or if you are writting to a terminal or network socket)

On my system, this means the buffer size is the block size of the filesystem it is writing the data (this is 16kb) and you don't have to mangle with buffer capacities, buffer sizes, or handling partially filled buffers.

Another thing is that `read(2)` is a system call.  The kernel implements it.  And the way to signal that we have reached `EOF` is unblocking the input process and giving to it zero bytes.  If it failed, your whole system would be failing.  Indeed, `<stdio.h>` uses it too.  It's not possible that you get 0 from `read()` without having reached the end of the file.  See how I check two things, the contentLength you announce, ---probably you have measured the length of your file before, and it has grown---, in that case you will output only the specified bytes (as writing more would break the HTTP protocol, if this is what you are trying to do) to the output.

---

Another approach, which can be unavailable at your system is to use the  `sendfile(2)` system call.  This is a very powerfull system call that originated in Berkeley code, and avoids copying the data in and then out to the kernel, making it the most efficient in terms of speed and buffering.  The buffering here is done internally by the kernel, so for your snippet is the shortest in terms of memory footprint.   The kernel passes data for you from one open file descriptor to the other (well, it is not the kernel, but your process, running in kernel mode), allowing you to specify a starting `off_t` offset, and a bytecount.

This will lead to this code: (it still has a loop, as `sendfile(2)` can stop half done, due to different reasons)

The linux man page tells that `sendfile(2)` doesn't allow non seekable output files, you cannot use `O_APPEND`, so it has some drawbacks.  Beware also that the interface of `sendfile(2)` varies from system to system, being significatively different in BSD systems, for example.  Following is a linux version:

```
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void executeSetCommand(const char *filename, int contentLength)
{
    int out = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (out < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__":%d: fopen: %s: %s\n",
                __LINE__, filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(15);
    }
    do {
    off_t from_off = 0;
        ssize_t res = sendfile(0, out, &from_off, contentLength);
        if (res < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, __FILE__":%d: sendfile: %s: %s\n",
                    __LINE__, filename, strerror(errno));
            exit(16);
        }
        contentLength -= res;
    } while (contentLength > 0);
    fclose(out);
    printf("Ok\n");
}
```

(**Note:**  As you didn't provide a complete, and verifiable example, I don't do it now, so beware that my source code probably needs to be tested to verify it is correct, but probably you can do it too with sample code that is probably part of a homework assignment)

Comment: If you could guarantee that the input `fd` is a file, it's really hard to beat [`sendfile()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) for memory usage: `ssize_t bytes; do { bytes = sendfile( out, in, NULL, 32 * 1024 ); } while ( bytes > 0 );`

Comment: @AndrewHenle, of course.  I was about to put it too, but I finally forgot.  I'll add it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, be carefull because linux guys still claim differences between the API of `sendfile(2)` against the originators in BSD, making this system call highly unportable.  BSD interface is far more complete, although, allowing non-seekable (pipes, fifos or sockets) to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a char array with 4096 space that means you simply cannot put more than 4096 characters in it as a buffer

Consider it like a small glass you bought for yourself and now you're trying hard to fill it up with a bucket of water.

Comment: They're not trying to put more than 4096 bytes in the buffer. Each call to `read()` is limited by `maxReadSize`.

Comment: But on successive read calls the buffer should be overwritten, no?

Comment: @user23362834 Right. Each call should get the next 4096 bytes of the input, until you reach the content length or EOF.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you only test if `if (bytesRead < 0)` but not for end of file (bytesRead == 0)`.  You should break from the loop at end of file.
- The writing loop has a problem: you keep writing from the beginning of the buffer if `write` returns a short count.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int executeSetCommand(const char *filename, int contentLength) {
    int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,
                  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    ssize_t totalWritten = 0; // Total bytes written so far
    int loopcounter = 0;

    while (totalWritten < contentLength) {
        loopcounter++;
        fprintf(stderr, "loopcounter %d\n", loopcounter);
        // Read up to the size of the buffer or whatever is left to read to meet contentLength
        fprintf(stderr, "totalwritten: %zd\n", totalWritten);

        ssize_t readSize = sizeof(buffer);
        if (readSize > contentLength - totalWritten)
            readSize = contentLength - totalWritten;
        fprintf(stderr, "readSize: %zd\n", readSize);

        bytesRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, readSize);
        fprintf(stderr, "bytesRead: %zd\n", bytesRead);
        if (bytesRead <= 0) {
            if (bytesRead < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            }
            break;
        }

        ssize_t bufferPosition = 0;
        ssize_t bytesWritten = 0; // Bytes written in the current iteration
        while (bufferPosition < bytesRead) {
            bytesWritten = write(fd, buffer + bufferPosition, bytesRead - bufferPosition);
            fprintf(stderr, "bytesWritten: %zd\n", bytesWritten);
            if (bytesWritten <= 0) {
                if (bytesWritten < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "write error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "write error: no space available\n");
                }
                close(fd);
                return -1;
            }
            bufferPosition += bytesWritten;
            totalWritten += bytesWritten;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```